# Is there any way to get the value of a key using the key in laravel eloquent (similar to getting value from key in array)

Tags: laravel

We can get the value of a key by `$a['yourkey']` in PHP.

Is there any way to do this in laravel collection.

[image]

I just didn't want to use a loop so can i get the values under the key 340 without using a loop?

I want to code it this way in my view.

```
    @foreach($jobseeker[340] as $v){
        //Code here...
    }
```

Comment: You mean something like `$a['jobseeker'][340]`  ?

Comment: [`Collection::get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-get)

Comment: yes @apokryfos exactly.

Comment: Not sure I get you. Did that answer your question?

Comment: @user575257 cant i call it after i have initially fetched all data using get()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is:

```
$jobseeker->get(340);
```

Comment: cant i just get() and then later on call it to match how we call array index? @Rafik

Comment: May be `$jobseeker = $jobseeker->toArray();`. Then you can `$jobseeker[340]`.